# Идентификатор группы сообщества

Tags: java, vkontakte-api

Хочу сделать Longpoll запрос на сервер vk для бота, но сперва нужно получить ключ и адрес сервера, https://vk.com/dev/groups.getLongPollServer здесь ввожу group_id и делаю запрос(внизу есть опция для запроса) но когда делаю запрос через postman выдает

```
{
"error": {
    "error_code": 100,
    "error_msg": "One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: group_id is undefined",
    "request_params": [
        {
            "key": "oauth",
            "value": "1"
        },
        {
            "key": "method",
            "value": "groups.getLongPollServer"
        },
        {
            "key": "PARAMETERS",
            "value": ""
        },
        {
            "key": "v",
            "value": "5.74"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

в запросе отправляю

```
 {
"group_id": "165342907"
 }
```

На адрес 
https://api.vk.com/method/groups.getLongPollServer?PARAMETERS&access_token=***********&v=5.74  в урле все правильно, если что то меняю он соответственно возвращает ошибку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо вставить в url group_id, json не нужен

Comment: `в урле все правильно, если что то меняю он соответственно возвращает ошибку`

Comment: покажите конечный запрос, то есть что у вас вместо PARAMETERS

Comment: Таков апи, надо писать слово PARAMETERS.